# Get maximum qty discount and discount amount programmatically in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Is that possible to get maximum qty discount and discount amount values from Shopping Cart Price Rules programmatically in Magento?

Answer (score 1):

Information about Shopping Cart Price Rules are stored in the table salesrule (In Magento php code, you can use the model Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule). Amonst others, it contains the methods

```
getDiscountQty()
getDiscountAmount()
```